# link 1 website in another

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

how to pass the link which redirects to another website. for example consider abc is a website and another is xyz website. Within abc how to pass link xyz. Please give me the solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you try searching for similar in [google](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=p89DU5OBCMjR8gfi4oCIAg#q=how+to+add+link+to+website+in+asp.net)
?

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="http://www.xyz.com">website xyz</a>
```

just a simple link will do

Comment: website is in localhost

Comment: url is like http://localhost:54437/xyz/Type.aspx

Comment: What about the fact that it is localhost? local means only the computer you are using can access it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="http://www.xyz.com" Text="Visit XYZ Website!" Target="_blank" runat="server" />
```

Comment: the website is in local host.

Comment: url is like localhost:54437/xyz/Type.aspx